# Array unserialize issue returning null/false

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I've got an array being returned in this format:

```
a:1:{i:0;i:305;}
```

I can't seem to `unserialize()` it to access the `305`. Anyone have an idea on what I can do?

Query in WordPress:

```
$order_id = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id=" . $t->object_id . " AND meta_key='wpc_inv_order_id");
```

I attempted to use:

```
$str = $order_id->meta_value;
$a = unserialize($str);
var_dump($a);
echo $a;
```

which resulted in `bool(false)`.

However, it appears that by just doing `echo $order_id->meta_value;` it somehow unserialized itself and is now giving me the ID value in the serialized array.

So by doing:

```
$str = $order_id->meta_value;
echo $str;
```

I'm getting output `305` on the above.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could we see the original array?

Comment: I don't have it, I'm trying to edit another users initial plugin. The 305 is the id of a row in another table I need to access.

I'll attempt to find where it is input.

Comment: Should be just `unserialize("a:1:{i:0;i:305;}")[0];`

Comment: look in my answer. i did

Comment: @splash58 Ah yes, you're right.

Comment: Edit I'm dumb, I copied it with the string instead of inserting the array.

Comment: Could you share your code? You might have another issue interfering with your efforts.

Comment: `$order_id = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id=" . $t->object_id . " AND meta_key='wpc_inv_order_id");`

This is the sql call in Wordpress

Comment: Add that, and whatever code you had trying to unserialize it, to your question for easier reading :)

Comment: For some reason by just echoing the sql call, its outputting the id I needed. This is so weird...

Comment: Could you include any code you were using to unserialize and access the value?

Comment: @Stuart Wagner are you undestanding the problem now?

Comment: Wordpress must somehow unserialize the value itself upon being echo'd... I've got no idea how/why this works but it was figured out.

Comment: Odd. It seems the issue with your original attempt to unserialize is on WP's end. Regardless, I'm glad you got it working :)

Comment: joined previous speakers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking what is result of unserialize

```
$str = 'a:1:{i:0;i:305;}';
var_dump($a = unserialize($str));

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(305)
}
```

So take it by`$a[0];`

Comment: `$str = $order_id['meta_value'];
$a = unserialize($str);
echo $a[0];
var_dump($a);`

This is Bool(false) for everything

Comment: @Jacob  what is a result?

Comment: The result there was bool(false) for every case.

Comment: Wow... it appears the echo $str is outputting the number I need.